# Cannot display image in webpage

Tags: php

I have problem displaying my image after I upload my coding to online web hosting. When I do in  my localhost, I the image manage to retrieve out and manage to move to the accessory folder. But when I try in online, the image  upload do not move to the accessory folder that store the image and cannot be retrieve out. Below is my code:

adminadd.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_name");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $description=$_POST['description'];
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($image_temp,"accessory/".$image);
    $price=$_POST['price'];
    $category=$_POST['category'];

    $query="INSERT INTO product (name,product_description,price,catid,image) VALUES ('$name','$description','$price','$category','$image')";

    if(mysqli_query($connect, $query)){
        echo "<script>alert('Successfully inserted')</script>";

    }
}
?>
```

Can someone enlighten me with my problem. Appreciate alot.

Comment: Did you edit the code when running it on a different system? (In any way at all? e.g. to change the destination for the mode_uploaded_file function?)

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: I did not edit my code. It is the same when I do it in my localhost. But when upload to hosting, the image not able move to my accessory folder.

Comment: So your code, which works in test, has `"http://fypesystem.com/Shineacc/accessory/".$image` in it? That exact string?

Comment: No, I add this because now is in web hosting. Anything wrong with this?

Comment: What did you have there when it was working in test?

Comment: use an absolute path rather than a url

Comment: move_uploaded_file($image_temp,"accessory/".$image); 
Like this, when i do in test. I manage to move the image to folder, @Quentin

Comment: How @RamRaider?

Comment: for example `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploads' - though you would be better using a path outwith the directory root but depends what the end purpose is

Comment: Incidentally @Lawrence your site appears to have been hacked and is maliciously redirecting people to pornhub

Comment: The hack: https://imgur.com/a/gO0gn

Comment: How to delete the porn hub?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160849/discussion-between-ramraider-and-lawrence).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destination needs to be a **filename**, not a URL.

Typically, it is not possible to write to HTTP URLs (it requires the server to be set up to allow it, and for you to make a PUT request with appropriate authentication … `move_uploaded_file` can't do that).

Change `http://fypesystem.com/Shineacc/accessory/` to a directory path on your server's filesystem.

Comment: Directory path like how? Can you show me example please.

Comment: If your site hosted on linux you could simply do : 
move_uploaded_file($image_temp, '/var/www/html/Shineacc/accessory/'.$image);

make sure to replace the example path with yours

Comment: Directory paths do not start with `http://` not do they include hostnames!